# How do I have my WPF application to be running as a service in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture, windows-services, desktop-application

I have a WPF application and I want to have it run as a service how do i do it in C#?

Comment: I'm confused. WPF is an user interface technology, and services generally, do not have user interaction.

Comment: Yeah; in fact, services are *made* to obviate user interaction.

Comment: Do you just want your application to run on startup?

Comment: great running it at the startup also would be great for now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT** (Based on comment)

If you want to make the program run at startup the easiest would be to change the setup to create a shortcut of the application output (exe) in the below directories:

WIN 7: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
XP: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

**Original explanation**

Well given that a WPF application is a UI based application and a windows service is not, you would have to take out all of the interaction with the user from the application and then basically recreate it as a service.

There is no easy 1 step process to do this given that they are made to do 2 completely different things.

A service sits in the background and performs tasks that do not recuire user intput, and in most cases does not interact with the user except for a config file; Even though you can run the service to interact with the desktop but that works completely different from a normal wpf program.

A Wpf program on the under hand (as the presentation part of the name suggests) is made to interact with the user.

Why would you want to run it as a service? The whole point of a service is to run in the background with minimum user interaction.

Comment: i am designing an application that will post all running applications to a website

Comment: This sounds exactly like a service, sometimes it's better to create a normal application first because it's a huge mission to debug a service... Do as I said above though (original answer). Create a new service project(Loads of tutorials on the net, follow them step by step if it's your first service), add an application configuration file that will keep all the settings that will change over time and bob's your uncle

Answer (score 1):

Divide your app into two parts;

1. A Windows service app that runs in the background
   (possibly auto runs at dtartup.and runs on system account).
2. A user interaction app that communicates with.and controls
   the windows service.

Consider WCF to communicate between the two.

Read about SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) if you want to better understand this.

Comment: To auto-run your app, either use registry LU or M \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Run or as suggested in other answer, StartUp folder in StartMenu.